# Android - HttpClient only works once

Tags: android, httpclient

I'm opening an url in the background because when going to the [link](http://website.com/3020/like)  it 'likes' the article 3020

I'm doing this with HttpClient:

```
public static class LoadURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

              @Override
              protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                second_client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                String getURL = "http://website.com/" + id_string + "/like/";
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
                HttpResponse responseGet = second_client.execute(get, cookieStuff);

              Log.i("Response", String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));  

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
               return null;

              }

              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
               super.onPostExecute(result);
               Toast.makeText(AFragment.context, "Article liked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
              }
        }
```

The problem is that there are plenty of articles (3020-3021-3022 etc.) so the user will click multiple times the 'like' button. That means the LoadURL task is done multiple times but it only works the first time. All times after that it takes like 5+ minutes.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Or is there a better way than using HttpClient?

Comment: asynctask run on a single thread. They won't run parallely. You can use executor for this purpose.http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Comment: So in the onPostExecute I have to kill the AsyncTask? Can you maybe explain a little more?

Comment: How are you executing AsyncTask, creating AsyncTask object everytime for click button?

Comment: You need to run multiple tasks when user click Like Button right? So use a Executor. For more info on asynctask check the topic under Threading Rules @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I set the id_string to the article id the user wants to like and than I do: new LoadURL().execute(); @PareshMayani

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the web server is working well? 
1. First thing you should do is create a static instance of `DefaultHttpsClient` and use the same one every time, it should work well, I've used it a lot of times.
2. Take a look at [volley](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo), it is a new library google has released for networking

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate client only once and reuse it using ThreadedClientConnManager

```
HttpClient mClient;
 HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 100);
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme ("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

        ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);

        mClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
```

Now just reuse client

```
public static class LoadURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

              @Override
              protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {

                String getURL = "http://website.com/" + id_string + "/like/";
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
                HttpResponse responseGet = mClient.execute(get, cookieStuff);

              Log.i("Response", String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));  

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
               return null;

              }

              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
               super.onPostExecute(result);
               Toast.makeText(AFragment.context, "Article liked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
              }
        }
```

Comment: I have to put the HttpClient stuff in the onCreate?

Comment: Yes you can, it will work ok. But the better practice is to create separate class for http requests, or use IntentServices

Comment: This works! :D But sometimes it still takes some time.. Do you maybe know if there is a better way instead of using HttpGet? @Greensy

Comment: You can try HttpUrlConnection, there are a lot of tutorials, give it a try.But i thinks, you problem in lags, can be in wrong thread managment. Another Approach can be using BufferedEntity